# Messed With Android Partition

Tags: factory-reset, partitions, ext4

I tried to partition my android phone and messed up the internal partition system.

When I reset my system this message appears

E:Can't open "/cache/recovery"
E:Unable to mount "/cache"
E:format_volume: make ext4fs failed on /emmc@cache

Now (condition): my phone boots up but it stucks with just logo.

Phone Name : Walton Primo Gh3/GIONEE CTRL V4S
Chipset: MTK6582
Os Installed: CyanogenMod 12.2 (Custom)

Is there any way to recover it?

Comment: Mention the device name/model in the question..

Comment: Please check again now @GokulNC

Comment: Why don't you use SP flash tool to flash cache partition of your device?

Comment: As @Firelord mentioned above, download your phone flash file (ROM) and flash it with SP Flashtool. Untick all except system or android, cache.

Comment: I Tried with sp flash tools. But same problem remains. It just stuck with logo. Is there any way to re-partition it ?

Answer (score 0):

Hope you have fixed that issue by now. As it is a Walton device, flashing a ROM would have done the thing. 
However if you can go to the recovery, download a script to re-partition your system.
And, I think the current Walton devices have a fastboot option.

Answer (score 0):

if you can get into recovery mode you should back up all the working partitions, flash a new ROM, then restore the partitions you have, such as data and system